# bufferedReader now taking 10+ seconds to complete (Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Here is my code.

```
val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(FileReader(filelocation.toString()))
val xmlString = StringBuilder()
do {
    val line: String? = bufferedReader.readLine() ?: break
    xmlString.append(line.toString())
} while(true)
```

This used to take .5 to 1 second to complete. I had to redo my whole project, due to a lost hard drive.  Now, on the same XML file, this is taking 10+ seconds to complete.   How can I improve this?  The source file is an xml file about 12,000 lines long.

Comment: Have you seen the Idiomatic Kotlin page? In particular, you might like to read the recommended way of achieving [try-with-resources](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#java-7s-try-with-resources) in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't get anywhere close to seconds worth of time when reading a large XML file (I did my tests with a 120k line, 3 MB file), here's some code that does the same thing using the [`useLines`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/use-lines.html) function from the standard library which runs approximately 6 times as fast on my machine:

```
File(fileName).useLines { 
    xmlString.append(it) 
}
```

If you're doing file I/O in Kotlin, you might wanna look at all the other functions of the [`kotlin.io`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/index.html) package as well, it has many convenient solutions for such tasks.